# A question on the cubic solutions rotated by a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, complex-numbers

Currently, I am learning complex numbers at secondary school and a question has crossed my mind.

Suppose you have a cubic question:

$f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ , where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$

I've that the cubic equation **must** have 3 real solutions or 1 real solution and 2 complex solutions.

There is another theorem which the three solutions must add up to 0, for example: $-a+ib, -a-ib, c$ are the solutions, $(-2a+c) = 0, (-b+b)i = 0$. If I take a rotational matrix - let's say M - and rotate the solution by $\theta$ radians - for example $\frac{1}{6}\pi$ - such that all of the solutions are complex, would this contradict the previous statement of having 3 complex solutions or is this untrue?

I've tried talking to my teacher at school and they said they didn't have a clue so I'll post it on here and see if anyone has any insight on this question.

Comment: "*the cubic equation must have 3 real solutions or 1 real solution and 2 complex solutions*" $\;-\;$ *Only* if the coefficients of the cubic are real. Your new equation after substitution no longer has all coefficients _real_.

Comment: The solution don't add up to $0$, but to $-b/a$ (where $a$ and $b$ are coefficients of the cubic). See [Vieta's formulas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: Also worth mentioning: to rotate around $0$ in the complex plane, you don't need a matrix, just multiply by $e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: It is a bad notation to use $a,b,c$ in the coefficients and then also in the components of the roots.